# Smarty3 Template Loading with Relative Path Using include file

Tags: php, templates, include, smarty3, smarty2

Our Project Flipped from smarty 2 to smarty 3. when i am including a file using include file. 
it returns

> Error : Unable Load template.

Its working fine in smarty 2 but after flipped its not working in smarty 3 any Suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try 'testInstall' method and also setting the directories after you instantiate Smarty, in this example into '$smarty':

```
[...]
$smarty->setTemplateDir('somedir/templates/');
$smarty->setCompileDir('somedir/templates_c/');
$smarty->setConfigDir('somedir/configs/');
$smarty->setCacheDir('somedir/cache/');

$smarty->testInstall();
exit;
```